# Can my own Server communicate with mobile Application directly

Tags: php, mobile, webserver

I just want to know if my own design server can communicate directly with a mobile application (Android ,IOS ,BB).
I need to send some information in XML form to the app.
Regards

Comment: From HTTP server
Regards

Comment: if your design server is on the same network with your mobile device, then they can communicate each other, otherwise, your server need to be publicly connected to the internet, and use your mobile connection or wifi to connect your device to your server

Comment: You mean just your server not a webpage? Because you can't do those things with php. PHP can send a request, but not as a job, like php sends every 10 minutes XML to your app.